# What are the groups containing dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I'm a little embarrassed to ask this but I couldn't answer it myself.

I am looking the groups that contains $D_4$ and larger than $D_4$. Here is what I think:

We cannot say $D_4 \subseteq D_n, n\ge 5$ because their group operation are different. But what else? $D_4$ doesn't lie in $S_4$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $D_4$ absolutely lies within $S_4$. You have 
$$
D_4 \cong \langle (1\ \ 3), (1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)\rangle
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann, How did I forget that? Any group is isomorphic to subgroup of $S_n$ so can I say that $D_4$ lies in $S_n , n\ge 4?$

Comment: Do you mean "contains" as a subgroup?

Comment: Also, $D_4\cong K$ for some $K\le D_{2n}$ for some $n$.

Comment: $D_4$ arises as a subgroup of really many groups. Why do you want to study this? Usually it is the other way around, i.e., what are the subgroups of $D_4$.

Comment: I would say that the question of whether a group $G$ is literally **contained in** another group has limited group theoretic interest (perhaps it has some set theoretic interest...). To a group theorist, there is more interest in whether $G$ is a **isomorphic to a subgroup of** another group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can't be abelian.

What about products?    For any group $G,$ $$G×D_4,G*D_4.$$

Direct and free, respectively.   Don't think you can always do a semi-direct or a wreath;   but sometimes.

Also,  many dihedral groups contain embedded $D_4$'s (some contain more than one copy of $D_4$).

$S_n,n\ge4$ contains $D_4.$